# Aussprache Beta

Tags: pronunciation

Was ist die korrekte Aussprache für den griechischen Buchstaben in Deutsch? Falls es einen Unterschied macht, wäre ich insbesondere an der Verwendung in Physik/Mathematik interessiert, wo er zum Beispiel als Winkel oder beim Beta-Zerfall auftritt.

Ich habe sowohl Beta mit langem "e" (wie in Rote Beete) als auch mit kurzem ("Betta") gehört.

[Diese Quelle](https://forvo.com/word/beta/#de) hat beide Aussprachen, und zwar wenn Beta alleine steht mit langem "e" und in der Kombination *Memantin Beta* mit kurzen "e".

Wiktionary sagt: [ˈbeːta], [ˈbɛta]. Das müssten die beiden Versionen sein, richtig?

Allerdings finde ich keine Information ob es einen Unterschied in der Aussprache je nach Anwendungsgebiet gibt, oder ob es ansonsten eine allgemeingültige Regel gibt wie man den Buchstaben ausspricht.

Ein paar Beispiele nach Wiktionary:

- Beta-Version [ˈbeːta] und [ˈbɛta]
- Beta-Zerfall/Betastrahlung [ˈbeːta]
- Betablocker [ˈbeːta] und [ˈbɛta]

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher?

Comment: Ich glaube die erste Version (mit langem "e") wird favorisiert. Ich kann aber IPA schlecht lesen, daher die Frage.

Comment: Warum ist die Frage "off-topic"?

Comment: Weil man die Antwort in einem Wörterbuch findet.

Comment: @DavidVogt Ich habe meine Frage etwas konkretisiert. Sicherlich findet man die Aussprache einzelner Wörter im Wörterbuch. Meine Frage zielt jedoch darauf ab, ob in bestimmten Fachgebieten die eine oder andere Aussprache bevorzugt wird.

Comment: @user1583209 _betta_ ist nicht üblich.

Comment: @user1583209: betta halte ich durchaus für üblich. Ich selbst würde Beta-Version und Beta-Zerfall stets kurz aussprechen, bei Betablocker sind mir beide Varianten gleichermaßen vertraut.

Comment: Ich würde sogar *drei* Aussprachevarianten zur Diskussion stellen, nämlich  /be:ta/, /beta/ und /bɛta/, also das "e" geschlossen und lang, geschlossen und kurz oder offen und kurz. Persönlich neige ich zur ersten oder zweiten Variante.

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe Physik studiert und dabei durchaus gelegentlich die Aussprache mit kurzem 'e' gehört (also *betta*), aber der Normalfall ist ein langes 'e'.
Ich halte das eher für einen Regionalismus, so wie in manchen Gegenden Deutschlands Spaß mit kurzem 'a' (also Spass) gesprochen wird.

Comment: Ich sage auch "Betta". "Beeeta" klingt für mich etwas gestelzt.

Comment: @äüö und wie nennst Du die Abfolge der Buchstaben? Alphabeet oder Alphabett?

Comment: Alphabeet, aber da ist das auch OK so (aus seinen eigenen unerfindlichen Gründen LOL ;-) )

Comment: +1 für Regionalismus. Das wissenschaftliche Umfeld hat nicht wirklich etwas mit der Aussprache zu tun, die Herkunft schon eher. Auch immer ein schönes Beispiel: China (China, Kina, Schina), jedoch ist hier die korrekte Ausprache definiert.

Comment: @äüö Ich bin ganz Deiner Meinung. Beeeta kenne ich auch nur in der Aussprache von "Betamax".